# Angular RxJS Subscription Reference Value

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, formarray, formgroups

***Update**: Previously the question didn't clearly explain that the `FormGroup` object is part of a `FormArray`.*

---

I am listening to value changes of a `FormGroup` object which is part of a `FormArray`, however the passed value seem to be just a value that's not referencing to the original `FormGroup` object.

```
formArrayObject.controls.forEach(formGroupObject => {
    formGroupObject
        .valueChanges
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.someUnsubscriber$))
        .subscribe(updatedFormGroupObject => {

            // this doesn't update formGroupObject
            updatedFormGroupObject.anotherProperty = true;
    });
}
```

How to update another properties of the updated `formGroupObject` inside the subscription callback?

The problem is not knowing which `formGroupObject` that was updated, therefore not knowing which `formGroupObject` to update.

I wish `updatedFormGroupObject` would return a reference to the updated object, but it didn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AbstractControl` won't update itself after changing properties coming from `valueChanges`.

You'll need to update the form value yourself:

```
formGroupObject.patchValue({
   anotherProperty: true,
});
```

... or maybe you want to use `setValue()` but in this case it should be the same:

```
formGroupObject.setValue({
   ...updatedFormGroupObject,
   anotherProperty: true,
});
```

Comment: Thanks @martin! this works, but I realised I didn't explain the issue properly. formGroupObject is part of a `FormArray` so part of the problem is knowing which array item that was updated. I'll update the question

Comment: That's almost the same thing, you can get the index of what `formGroupObject` emitted from `forEach((formGroupObject, index) => ...)` and then call `formArrayObject.at(index).patchValue(...)`